# cx_freeze builds app but displays error: *** is not a Mach-O file

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to make a python application with cx_freeze. I used the `cxfreeze-quickstart` option to make the setup file. It is a basic application that uses a tkinter GUI and only has two import statement, both standard python libraries: `from tkinter import Tk; import webbrowser`

Here is the setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('TheApp.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='TheApp',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'Basic App',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

When I run `python3 setup.py bdist_mac` to create a `.app` it runs and compiles an app but it runs through hundreds of files saying there is an error (the last one that shows up):

`error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: build/TheApp-1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/email/_encoded_words.pyc is not a Mach-O file`

When I click on the `.app` it opens and closes immediately. If I go to the folder `TheApp/build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/` and click on the Unix executable named TheApp then it opens and runs properly. The results are the same if I try the bdist_dmg option. Does anyone know how to fix the Mach-O error or how to solve this problem if that is not the issue?

Comment: We get a ton of these errors and the app still works.... I think it's not these errors that's the problem.